# Текстовые файлы и string

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Читаю с input файла, читаю посимвольно, чтобы отделить в каждую строку предложение и записываю всё в output файл. С этого output файла я читаю самое последнее предложение и проверяю, что в конце '?', а в самом начале 'Кто' или 'кто'. Если условия не совпадают, то вывожу соответсвующее сообщение. Работал с отладчиком, отладчик показывал, что string word записывает в себя строки. Но по какой-то причине компиляция выдаёт ошибку:

"Expression: string subscript out of range

For information on how your program can cause an assertion failure, see the Visual c++ documentation on asserts"
Пожалуйста, помогите мне найти в чём заключается ошибка. Я не могу понять, почему выдаётся данная проблема **(переводить мне её не нужно, мне нужна помощь, чтобы разобраться, а гениев программирования я прошу либо помочь, либо просто идти дальше)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    string in,ou, word;
    cout << "Введите входной файл" << endl;
    getline(cin, in);
    cout << "Введите выходной файл" << endl;
    getline(cin, ou);
    ifstream file;
    fstream out;
    file.open(in);
    out.open(ou);
    int n = 0;
    char ch = ' ';
    bool M = TRUE;

    if (!file.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Файл не найден! 1" << endl;
    }
    else
    {   
        while (!file.eof())
        {
            file.get(ch);
            if ((ch == '.') || (ch == '!') || (ch == '?'))
            {
                out << ch;
                file.get(ch);
                if (ch == ' ')
                {
                    out << endl;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (ch == '\n')
                {
                    out << ' ';
                }
                else
                {
                    out << ch;
                }
                
            }
        }
        out.close();
    }
    file.close();

    in = "";
    ch = ' ';
    out.open(ou);
    if (!out.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Файл не найден! 2" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        word = "";
        while (!out.eof())
        {
            getline(out, word);
            if (out.eof())
            {
                if (word[word.size() - 1] == '?')
                {
                    ch = word.c_str()[n];
                    if ((ch == 'К') || (ch == 'к'))
                    {
                        n = n + 1;
                        ch = word.c_str()[n];
                        if (ch == 'т')
                        {
                            n = n + 1;
                            ch = word.c_str()[n];
                            if (ch == 'о')
                            {
                                n = n + 1;
                                ch = word.c_str()[n];
                                if (ch == '-')
                                {
                                    cout << "Спасибо за информацию! 5" << endl;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    cout << "Конь в пальто,";
                                    while (M)
                                    {
                                        cout << ch;
                                        n = n + 1;
                                        ch = word.c_str()[n];
                                        if (ch == '?')
                                        {
                                            M = FALSE;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    cout << "!" << endl;
                                }

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                cout << "Спасибо за информацию! 4" << endl;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cout << "Спасибо за информацию! 3" << endl;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cout << "Спасибо за информацию! 2" << endl;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "Спасибо за информацию! 1" << endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image: как выглядит input и output файл]

Comment: Во-первых: `if (word[word.size() - 1] == '?')`. А что произойдёт, если `word.size()` возвратит `0`(пустая строка)?. Во-вторых: `n = n + 1; ch = word.c_str()[n];`. А что произойдёт, если `n` станет равным `word.size()`? Правильно, произойдёт выход за границы строки.

Comment: @LShadow77, спасибо, что объяснили. До моей головы так и не дошло, как всё-таки без магий с бубном прочитать самую последнюю строку, используя только одну переменную string. Поэтому я добавил ещё одну строковую переменную (куда записывал предложения). И как только переменная word находила пустую строку, то новая переменная (содержащая в себе последнее предложение) начинало работать с этим предложением.
Так же я не понимаю, почему не работает цикл .eof(), надо будет почитать по этому моменту.

Answer (score 0):

Если кому-то стало интересно, как можно решить данную проблему. Вроде работает нормально, но мне кажется, это очень плохо выглядит. И можно сделать лучше.

```
if (!out.is_open())
{
    cout << "Файл не найден! 2" << endl;
}
else
{
    word, coutword = "";
    getline(out, word);
    while (M)
    {       
        if (word.size() == 0)
        {
            if (coutword[coutword.size() - 1] == '?')
            {
                ch = coutword.c_str()[n];
                if ((ch == 'К') || (ch == 'к'))
                {
                    n = n + 1;
                    ch = coutword.c_str()[n];
                    if (ch == 'т')
                    {
                        n = n + 1;
                        ch = coutword.c_str()[n];
                        if (ch == 'о')
                        {
                            n = n + 1;
                            ch = coutword.c_str()[n];
                            if (ch == '-')
                            {
                                cout << "Спасибо за информацию! 5" << endl;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                cout << "Конь в пальто,";
                                while (M)
                                {
                                    cout << ch;
                                    n = n + 1;
                                    ch = coutword.c_str()[n];
                                    if (ch == '?')
                                    {
                                        M = FALSE;
                                    }
                                }
                                cout << "!" << endl;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cout << "Спасибо за информацию! 4" << endl;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cout << "Спасибо за информацию! 3" << endl;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "Спасибо за информацию! 2" << endl;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Спасибо за информацию! 1" << endl;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            coutword = "";
            coutword = word;
        }
        getline(out, word);
    }
}
```

Comment: я забыл дополнить окончание цикла в условия